# Measuring probability of random variables, when you're given the standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given assignment:

None of the 2500 independent random variables standard deviation doesn't exceed the number 3. Measure the probability, that these random variables arithmetic mean and the expected values arithmetic mean absolute value does not exceed 0.3

Given answer: $P>=0.96$

The problem I am facing is that I don't actually know what should I do or how should I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
P\biggl(\biggl|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k-\operatorname E\biggl[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\biggr]\biggr|\ge a\biggr)
\le\frac{\operatorname{Var}[n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]}{a^2}.
$$
Since the random variables are independent, we have that
$$
\operatorname{Var}\biggl[\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\biggr]=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{Var}X_k
$$
The standard deviation of each of these random variables does not exceed $3$. Hence, the variance of each of these random variables does not exceed $9$. Set $a=0.3$, $n=2500$, to obtain
$$
\frac{\operatorname{Var}[n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]}{a^2}\le\frac{2500^{-2}\cdot2500\cdot9}{0.3^2}=0.04.
$$
If we multiply both sides of the first inequality by $-1$ and add $1$ to both sides of the inequality, we obtain
$$
P\biggl(\biggl|\frac1{2500}\sum_{k=1}^{2500}X_k-\operatorname E\biggl[\frac1{2500}\sum_{k=1}^{2500}X_k\biggr]\biggr|<0.3\biggr)
\ge0.96.
$$
I hope this is useful.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough. A big thank-you to you!

Comment: @Janno You're welcome!